# How to unindex a single blog in Multisite?

Tags: multisite, search

Is there anyway to un-index a single blog in Multisite from search engines ?

Answer (score 1):

Each site in Multisite has its own search engine setting -- in your site's Admin pages, go to Settings > Reading, and check the `Discourage search engines from indexing this site` box.

The URL should be along the lines of `example.com/site-name/wp-admin/options-reading.php`